# SharePoint repair after unknown failure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, configuration, solution-deployment, iis7

Few days ago something happened in my machine (for development - Win7 ver 6.1 (7601 SP1) ) and I saw blue screen two times.

STOP 0x0000007A
Physical dump fails with status 0xC000009c

I scan my HDD and after some small repair system seems to works fine. But when I try now do some deployment on my sharePoint site via VS2010 I am geting message:

Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': A timeout has occurred while invoking commands in SharePoint host process.

[image]

I check services and all are running also features are turned on according to [msdn installation guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

I restart WAS and W3SVC with PowerShell

> PS C:\Windows\system32> restart-service WAS -force
>   PS C:\Windows\system32> restart-service W3SVC -force

in task manager services are running. (I also try to kill processes to restart it)

I also try to run SharePoint configuration wizard and it tells me:

```
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  ERR                            Caught an exception when trying to get the version of IIS.  We treat this as IIS not being installed
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                            Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                                Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                                  Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language Polish (Poland)
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                                  Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is Wystąpił wyjątek typu {0}. Dodatkowe informacje o wyjątku: {1}
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                                Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                            Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  ERR                            Wystąpił wyjątek typu     System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException. Dodatkowe informacje o wyjątku: Wykonanie serwera nie powiodło się.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Wykonanie serwera nie powiodło się.

w System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
w System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
w System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_SchemaClassName()
w Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PreRequisiteChecks.IsRightVersionOfIis(Int32& current, Int32& minimumAllowed)
w Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PreRequisiteChecks.IsIisInstalled()
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                          Leaving function PreRequisiteChecks.IsIisInstalled
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  ERR                          IIS is not installed

//others logs
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  ERR                          Task setup validation threw an exception
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                          Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                            Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                              Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                                Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language Polish (Poland)
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                                Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is Wystąpił wyjątek typu {0}. Dodatkowe informacje o wyjątku: {1}
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                              Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                            Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  INF                          Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
11/04/2013 10:32:34  1  ERR                          Wystąpił wyjątek typu Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException. Dodatkowe informacje o wyjątku: Internetowe usługi informacyjne nie są zainstalowane. Należy zainstalować Internetowe usługi informacyjne, aby móc używać Kreatora konfiguracji produktów programu SharePoint.
```

It says that my IIS is not installed.

I try to unchecked all features about IIS and install it again but after restarting machine I got message that not all features were able to activate.

I have access to sites (administration and my) via browser.

I do not have idea what is wrong and why suddenly I am cannot deploy my solution in my environment. If someone give me a clue or solution I will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disabled all features IIS
2. restart machine
3. from command line activate features:

> start /w pkgmgr
>   /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;
>   IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;
>   IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;
>   IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;
>   IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;
>   IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-DigestAuthentication;
>   IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;
>   IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;
>   IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;
>   WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;WCF-HTTP-Activation;
>   WCF-NonHTTP-Activation

now SharePoint configuration wizard finished without failure.

next:

1. After resetting IIS my sites has not binding
2. I again run sherpoint configuration wizard
3. It changes my features so I again activate it using command line (otherwise I have blank page on my central administration site).
4. In IIS manger I add binding to my other site (http, 80, *)
5. After run VS2010 I deploy solution without problems.